# Retrofit with MVVM

Tags: android, mvvm, retrofit2

I am new with using MVVM, and from searching I found that the implementation and calling of Retrofit service will be in the ViewModel but my problem is that I want to take the response of the Retrofit Api call and pass it to recyclerView. How can I do this if though I dint haev any view in ViewModel, any suggestion please ?

```
    services.getData().enqueue(new Callback<Data>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Data> call, Response<Data> response) {
          //  the response contains an arrayList, that I want to pass it to recyclerView

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Data> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform the following steps :-

- `Observe` the response in *Activity/Fragment* which needs to *implement* `LifeCycleOwner`.
- `onChanged(..)` method of the observer when you receive the data, set it to your `view`.

> how i could do this while i cannot put any view in ViewModel ?

Technically speaking , view model is the *bridge* between your **Repository** and your **Activity**, it fetches the data and holds it whenever the data is *changed*. **You do not need to put in Views inside the ViewModel class.** ( the `recyclerView` will be in the activity *itself*)

See -- > [ViewmodelWithRetrofit.](https://proandroiddev.com/mvvm-architecture-viewmodel-and-livedata-part-1-604f50cda1)